# ListView RowDetailsTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

How can I make a `RowDetailsTemplate` like `Datagrid` inside a `ListView`?

I've imagined to add at the bottom of my grid a Block that contain the rowdetails:

```
    <ListView
        Grid.Row="1"
        x:Name="listView"
        VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
        VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
        ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
        dz:GridViewSort.AutoSort="True"
        dz:VirtualListLoadingIndicator.IsAttached="True" Margin="0,0,0,-15"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ListeArticles}" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView ColumnHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewColumnHeaderTemplate}">
                <GridViewColumn Width="60" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Data.Article.ART_NUM}" Header="Reference" dz:GridViewSort.PropertyName="Article.ART_NUM" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Data.Article.ART_LIB}" Header="Designation" dz:GridViewSort.PropertyName="Article.ART_LIB" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Data.Article.ART_PRIX}" Header="Prix" dz:GridViewSort.PropertyName="Article.ART_PRIX" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data.Article.STOCK}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Data.Article.SOMETHINGELSE}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

But how to pass the row data to the stackpanel content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use SelectedArticle when a row is selected and then bind the StackPanel to the this SelectedArticle data:

1.SelectedArticle:

```
    public Article SelectedArticle
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedArticle;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedArticle = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedArticle");       
        }
    }
```

2.Xaml:

```
   <Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView
    Grid.Row="0"
    x:Name="listView"
    VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
    VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
    ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ListeArticles}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedArticle}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView >
                <GridViewColumn Width="60" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ART_NUM}" Header="Reference"  />
                <GridViewColumn Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ART_LIB}" Header="Designation" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ART_PRIX}" Header="Prix" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedArticle.STOCK}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedArticle.SOMETHINGELSE}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```